# Iterate calculate field in multiple tables in ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, field-calculator, table, iteration

I would like to iterate calculate field in multiple tables using ArcGIS Model Builder.
The figure below explains details of the calculations. My existing model calculates value only for the first table.
[image]

Any direction would be valuable.

Comment: I understand you are thinking the issue is with the calculate field tool, but it would be helpful if you would edit your question to include a screen shot or describe the parameters of the iterator as well.  Also, please go into the environment settings in ArcCatalog/ArcMap (whichever you're running the model from) and tell us if the "Overwrite the outputs of geoprocessing operations" setting is checked or not.  Knowing some of these extra details would likely help you get a more complete answer to your question.

Comment: Why not standardise the field you want to calculate into by adding a field that has the same name then calculate into that?

Comment: Thanks both John and Hornbydd. John - I retried after enabling 'overwrite' geoprocessing; but the same result, model calculates only the first table.       Hornbydd - Sorry, forgot to mention that the field I want to calculate has the same name as the filename. Later, I want to join all tables with column name as file name, which are unique (and not GRID_CODE).

Comment: I've added new field in each table (field name = file name) to get rid of uniform GRID_CODE column in each table.

Answer (score 1):

ModelBuilder only allows one iterator per model.  I would [integrate a model within a model](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002w0000007p000000) in order to iterate over multiple tables.

Answer (score 1):

If your **new fields have a pattern in their naming** (e.g., [table_name]_y as in your snapshots), you can use [inline variable substitution](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Examples_of_inline_model_variable_substitution/002w0000005w000000/). More specifically, if you change Field Name parameter to %Name%_y, this will transfer all GRID_CODE values to this field in your individual DBFs.